# How to get fields with same name as class parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, case-class

Take a simple class like the following:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int) {}
```

Now, when I instantiate this class, I typically want its users to be able to use `name` and `age`. Like:

```
val ronald = new Person("Ronald", 22)
val ronaldsName = ronald.name  // <-
```

This doesn't work of course unless I either define a **getter** called `name`, or make `Person` a **case class**. The latter is an easy solution, but I sort of feel like I'm abusing case classes?

Still the former is kind of a little inconvenient since I can't simply:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
  def name = name
}
```

So, then I would have to rename the first `name` in the class's constructor to something else, like `personName` or `_name` or `n`. But that is sort-of confusing and far less elegant in my eyes. It's the same concept/variable/value, so it should have the exact same name, right?

So ... what is the best or correct practice here? It's *so* tempting to just add that `case`.

Comment: If you're not intending to inherit from your class, I believe case classes are the way to go.

Comment: @BlakePettersson It depends on whether you want their equality semantics, which you do often but not always.

Comment: @BlakePettersson So, you it's semantically correct to use them even if you're never going to use them in a `case`-expression? I like the convenience of case-classes, but the prefix `case` (misleadingly) indicates that it's used for *pattern matching*..(?)

Comment: Case classes is syntactical sugar for automagically implementing equals and hashCode, as well as automatically creating a companion object for instantiating the case class. Unless you require different equals and hashCode semantics (as @AlexeyRomanov states) then I would argue that it is correct. Inheritance would break the implicit equals contract, which is why you should use a normal class if you require that. http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/case-classes-are-cool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add `val` to turn your parameters into public fields of your class:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
             ^^^               ^^^
```

Case classes, as you noticed, do this by default.

Comment: So simple. Thanks! But I want to understand Scala as deeply as possible..: Is this a **syntactic sugar** for some other expression somehow? (In the same way that `case class`es are?). If so, can you direct me (us) to some article that explains it? :)

Comment: You can define a field either in the constructor’s parameter list or in the body of the class. This is not really syntactic sugar — there is no other way to write this that is fully equivalent to it.

Comment: It used to be pure syntactic sugar (pre scala 2.8) in the sense that the example was indistinguishable from `class Person(_name: String, _age: Int) { val name = _name; vale age = _age }`. But the addition of named parameters in scala 2.8 have had the unfortunate side effect that the second (manual) solution exposed the ugly `_name` and `_age` parameter names to the outside. Since then there is indeed no other way to have the same nice non mangled name both for the parameter and the field than to prefix the parameter with `val`.